# Byte array to Signed integer in Delphi

Tags: delphi

source array(4 bytes)

```
[$80,$80,$80,$80] =integer 0
[$80,$80,$80,$81] = 1
[$80,$80,$80,$FF] = 127
[$80,$80,$81,$01] = 128
```

need to convert this to integer.

below is my code and its working at the moment.

```
function convert(b: array of Byte): Integer;
var
  i, st, p: Integer;
  Negative: Boolean;
begin
  result := 0;
  st := -1;
  for i := 0 to High(b) do
  begin
    if b[i] = $80 then Continue // skip leading 80
    else
    begin
      st := i;
      Negative := b[i] < $80;
      b[i] := abs(b[i] - $80);
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  if st = -1 then exit;
  for i := st to High(b) do
  begin
    p := round(Power(254, High(b) - i));
    result := result + b[i] * p;
    result := result - (p div 2);
  end;
  if Negative then  result := -1 * result
end;
```

i'm looking for a better function?

**Update:**

file link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByBA4QF-YOggZUdzcXpmOS1aam8/view?usp=sharing

- in uploaded file ID field offset is from 5 to 9

**NEW:**
Now i got into new problem which is decoding date field
 
Date field hex [$80,$8F,$21,$C1] -> possible date 1995-12-15
* in uploaded file date field offset is from 199 to 203

Comment: Please define "better"

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place for code review

Comment: @JensBorrisholt Less code lines and fast.

Comment: If this code works and you are looking for improvements, you are welcome to post it to [Code Review](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Don't use a dyn array. Fixed length array. Don't pass by value. Use const. Don't use floating point. Don't use IntPower even. Hard code 254**i.

Comment: What's more, it is still unclear what the algorithm is from the examples. The code is clear enough, but the code contains way more than your examples.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide more samples with interpreted values verified by any actual existing sw displaying those values. A few values in ranges -1..-127, -128..-255, -256..-16000, +256..+16000 would be sufficient. I believe there is an error in the algorithm, but that can't be assessed with the sofar presented values. Also, in your previous (now deleted) question you said the field is an autoincrementing record id field in a data base. What is the db, what is the original sw using that db?

Comment: Thanks for the uploaded file! As it is only 20 records, it doesn't really help in reviewing your algorithm. Could you please provide the record id bytes for the 260th and 520th record, alternatively upload the whole file as a original binary file without any alteration. Please also answer my previous comment regarding db brand and sw.

Comment: @TomBrunberg db brand and sw = unknown. full file uploaded!

Comment: are u sure in `[$80,$80,$81,$01] = 128` ? by logic it should be `[$80,$80,$81,$00] = 128; [$80,$80,$81,$01] = 129` - and then it would boil down to a single subtraction operation! // if not can you hexedit a [$80,$80,$81,$00] into the file and check how db engine would parse it ?

Comment: I open the attached in hex viewer and there obviously are strings like "003/08/200603/08/2006" like "GENERAL" like "0001 40284" - looking like semi-textual a la dbf

Comment: @Arioch'The, see my comment at my answer. ($80,$80,$80,$FF) and ($80,$80,$81,$00) and similar values does not exist in the number series.

Comment: @LURD ($80,$80,$80,$FF) dos exist but not  ($80,$80,$81,$00). this is a null($00) delimited file so no $00 in hex values block.

Answer (score 1):

Just an example of some improvements as outlined by David.

- The array is passed by reference as a const.
- The array is fixed in size.
- The use of floating point calculations are converted directly into a constant array.

---

```
Const
  MaxRange = 3;
Type
  TMySpecial = array[0..MaxRange] of Byte;

function Convert(const b: TMySpecial): Integer;
var
  i, j: Integer;
  Negative: Boolean;
Const
  // Pwr[i] = Round(Power(254,MaxRange-i));
  Pwr: array[0..MaxRange] of Cardinal = (16387064,64516,254,1);
begin
  for i := 0 to MaxRange do begin
    if (b[i] <> $80) then begin
      Negative := b[i] < $80;
      Result := Abs(b[i] - $80)*Pwr[i] - (Pwr[i] shr 1);
      for j := i+1 to MaxRange do
        Result := Result + b[j]*Pwr[j] - (Pwr[j] shr 1);
      if Negative then
        Result := -Result;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := 0;
end;
```

Note that less code lines is not always a sign of good performance.
Always measure performance before optimizing the code in order to find real bottlenecks.
Often code readability is better than optimizing over the top.

And for future references, please tell us what the algorithm is supposed to do.

---

Code for testing:

```
const
  X : array[0..3] of TMySpecial =
    (($80,$80,$80,$80), // =integer 0
     ($80,$80,$80,$81), // = 1
     ($80,$80,$80,$FF), // = 127
     ($80,$80,$81,$01)); // = 128
var
  i,j: Integer;
  sw: TStopWatch;
begin
  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  for i := 1 to 100000000 do
    for j := 0 to 3 do
      Convert(X[j]);
  WriteLn(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: `shr 1` is a bit odd. Won't compiler turn `div 2` into that anyway. But another const array would surely be quicker.

Comment: @david, I did do another const array first, but i think this is not as efficient as the division. And it looks like the shr is better than div 2. (Turns into a sar/jns/adc operation instead of just shr).

Comment: That's only because `p` (and `Pwr` in your code) is erroneously declared as a signed value. And I find it hard to believe that lookup + shift is faster than lookup.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, just did a quick test for another const array. In 32 bit it is more or less the same performance but in 64 bit, the shr faster.

Comment: OK, I guess the point is that my version is 2 lookups, and your version is 1 lookup plus shift. Because the optimiser can recognise that the second lookup is the same as the first.

Comment: Although my tests suggest that 2 lookups are slightly faster. Anyway, there's little in it. This function is unlikely to be a bottleneck since the input comes from a DB!!!

Comment: thanks @LURD. im using your one but still had no way to verify this is 100% correct with big numbers.

Comment: @RangaMK, in your updated question it looks as though you are not sure if your algorithm is correct. What is the relation between dates and the algorithm, or more specifically, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @LURD i think date is also in number format.   "what problem are you trying to solve?" I have 2 questions 1.Decode number field  2.decode date field

Comment: After `($80,$80,$80,$FE)` comes `($80,$80,$81,$01)` in your example file. So to fix that you need to change `Result := Result + b[j]*Pwr[j] - (Pwr[j] shr 1);` into `Result := Result + b[j]*Pwr[j] - ((Pwr[j]+1) shr 1);`. But we need larger number examples to verify further levels.